# global search and replace in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I use the database of mysql by a certain system now.

For data structure, there is table around 10-35 in five DB each, and there is by column around 5-40 on one table more.

Well, I think whether I cannot substitute the character string that there is that there is in data of the whole these databases for a lump.

Will not there be anything, the good method?

**Suggested translation**

> I currently use mysql as my DBMS There
>   are 5 databases and each currently
>   contains between 10 to 35 tables. Each
>   table has between 5 to 40 columns.
>
> I want to do a global replace on the
>   whole system replacing some string
>   with another, e.g. replace "President
>   Bush" by "President Obama". I want to
>   do the replace all at once. Is there
>   any way to do this?

Comment: Frankly, this makes no sense.

Comment: English clearly isn't your first language: not a problem, but I think you need to find a friend to help you write the question in a way which will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First off, to translate what I think you are saying:

> I currently use mysql as my DBMS
>   There are 5 databases and each currently contains between 10 to 35 tables. Each table has between 5 to 40 columns.
>
> I want to do a global replace on the whole system replacing some string with another, e.g. replace "President Bush" by "President Obama". I want to do the replace all at once. Is there any way to do this?

**Short answer**: no.

**Long**(er) **answer**: I do not believe there is any way to do this in one easy step. You could however accomplish this in multiple steps (get the database schemas, get the table schemas, go through every column, and.... so on)

Comment: +1 for the utterly valiant attempt at translation. I had *no* idea :)

Comment: I taught English in Japan for 4 years. I became rather accustomed to interpreting meaning from non-native English

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to do this. I needed to change all instances of my old email address with my new one. The problem is that I cannot use `UPDATE` or `REPLACE` because I do not even know the name of the databases it occurs in, let alone the table names, *let alone* the column names. I just want to do a simple string substitution *anywhere and everywhere* in the **entire system**.

Since my entire system is not *too* large, I simply dumped all of the databases with all of their tables to a single, giant `.SQL` file. Then I did a simple string search-and-replace, then imported the modified `.SQL` file back in.

Of course even if the MySQL system is large, you can do this with just the databases/tables that the target string occurs in.

You can also try a search in a hex-editor afterwards to see if the original string is still present.

Voilà.